# The Schwarz reflection principle and harmonic function (Big Rudin chapter 11)

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

In his book page 250 Exer 11:

Suppose that $I=[a,b]$,$\Omega$ is a region ,$I\subset\Omega$,$f$ is continuous in $\Omega$,and $f\in H(\Omega-I)$,prove that actually $f\in H(\Omega)$.

If I follow the route Rudin proved  SRP, I should prove that $Im(f)$ is a harmonic function 
in $\Omega$.But I don't know how to deal with it.

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't see how that is related to harmonic functions. The natural way to prove it is Morera's theorem.